# Media is not defined in cordova-plugin-media

Tags: cordova, audio, ionic-framework, media

I'm new to ionic. I have a problem with playing music with cordova-plugin-media. My error is shown in the picture below. I did everything said in this page but I couldn't get true answer. Please help me.
My html code :

`<div ng-controller="SoundController"> 
   <button class="button"   ng-click="play('https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Message%20in%20a%20bottle.mp3')" >
Play</button>
        </div>`

Angular code :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Acd.png)

[image]

Comment: Please, show us the code and what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: By the way, do you know cordova plugins don't work in the browser?

I'm guessing you're trying to do this in the browser. You should try in an emulator or device

Comment: @OliverGondža Gondža my code :   app.controller('SoundController', function($scope, $cordovaMedia) {
  $scope.play = function(src) {
        var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
        $cordovaMedia.play(media);
    }
 
    var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
        if(status == 1) {
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    } 
 

});

Comment: @Ladmerc yes i know this.But i Thought when i do this in the browser , it shouldn't error.Am i right ?

Comment: No you're not. You have to manually check if running in the browser.

Comment: @Ladmerc how can run this code in browser ? I've run this in an emulator and didn't work but now i run in an emulator and have the another error `thr connection to the server is unsuccessful(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)`

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer :)

1-cordova plugins don't work in the browser.
2-cordova-plugin-media works less version of android(4.4).
3-for older version of android (4.0-4.3) you should use Crosswalk.
I'll hope its helpful:)